# newTA SMA OBV How to?

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to create a new indicator in R with quantmod's command newTA but i can't make it.

The indicator is a simple 20-day moving average of the OBV.

so far i tried this

```
getSymbols("GEK.AT")
addObvma20 <- newTA(SMA(OBV(Cl(GEK.AT), Vo(GEK.AT)), n=20))
# Error in newTA(SMA(OBV(Cl(GEK.AT), Vo(GEK.AT)), n = 20)): FUN required
# to be a function object
```

and this

```
addObvma20 <- newTA(SMA(OBV), n=20)
# Error in as.vector(x, mode):cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'
```

I would like some help creating this indicator.

Comment: Can I assume the title is unclear because I'm not familiar with the topic? Oh look! close votes...

Comment: You'll have to provide much more information in your question.  What have you tried so far?  What error or warning messages do you get?  As the question stands, you risk it being closed.  (And have you read the help for `?newTA` - this looks quite detailed and helpful?

Comment: I did read the ?newTA but did not help me much at all.

Comment: Perhaps you should re-read it.  `?newTA` clearly says that the first argument should be a function (and the argument is named `FUN`!) and you're not passing it a function.

Comment: Hint for everyone.  Download the data with `getSymbols("GEK.AT")`.  This creates a variable `GEK.AT` in your global environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting the example from the help page, I think you want `addTA` rather than `newTA`.

```
getSymbols("GEK.AT")
barChart(GEK.AT)
addTA(SMA(OBV(Cl(GEK.AT), Vo(GEK.AT)), n = 20))
```

Comment: Given the attempt to create the object `addObvma20`, it seems they really do want `newTA`.

Comment: ok i did this `addObvma20 <- newTA(SMA,OBV,n=20)` and I created the `addObvma20` indicator. After that i applied this function `chartSeries(GEK.AT,theme="white",TA=NULL)` to get the stock price chart. I used the `addObvma20()` function to get the indicator in the chart and i got this error message Error `in .Internal(inherits(x, what, which)) : 'x' is missing`. What should i do to fix this?